# jquery dynamic table id thead th selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery. May be my query looks some what dumb, but really I'm not understanding how to achieve below thing.

**Anyway, here is my query:**

I have some dynamic tables as below:

```
<table id='example1'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

<table id='example2'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I am trying as below:

```
$($('table').attr('id') ' thead th').each( function () {

}
```

Seems something wrong above, could anyone please correct?

I need to achieve as below:

```
$( dynamicTableId thead th).each(function () {

}
```

Comment: At the least, you will need to describe what seems wrong (i.e. what behaviour are you expecting for some specified inputs, and how are the results you're getting different).

Comment: As a suggestion, at first, learn basics of JavaScript then start using jQuery.

Comment: do you want to iterate over all the `th` elements or the `th` of specific `table`?

Comment: `$('table').attr('id')` will return the `id` of the first table, so you will have a selector like `example1  thead th`, where `example1` is used as an element selector not as a `id` selector. So no element will be selected

Comment: @ArunPJohny Then how do I make it as a Id selector ?

Comment: what is your objective here... which `th` elements do you want - only from `example1` or from both the tables

Comment: @Peter I feel above is having some syntax errors, iam not getting correct output because of it

Comment: @ArunPJohny It should just iterate th element of every dynamic table having ids as example1, example2 etc

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have the if you are trying to iterate over all the `th` elements, Just use the table as selector. You can also use an has attribute selector to make sure it has an id

```
$('table[id] thead th').each( function () {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess i have done in my project , here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for (var t=1; t < 4; t++) // Number of table 
{
    document.write("<table border='1' id='example"+t+"'>");

    for (var a=1; a < 5; a++)  // Number of row for table
    {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for(var b=1; b<4; b++)  // Number of column for table
        {
        document.write("<td>Table "+t +" " + b+"</td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
 document.write("</table>");
 document.write("<br/><br/><br/>");
}
</script>
```

There are better ways to do this, though!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.example thead th').each(function () { 
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<table id='example1' class="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table id='example2' class="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```